# fscanf keeps reading the first line

Tags: c, file, pointers, io, scanf

I'm trying to keep reading a file in a while loop. This loop calls another function that gets the file as a parameter, reads it and return what read. However the first function always calls the second one "from the start" and this leads to a loop where only the first line is read.
this is the code of the two functions:

```
void pgList_read(FILE *fp, pgList_t pgList){
  pg_t pg;
  while(pg_read(fp, &pg) == 1){
    pg_print(stdout, &pg, NULL);
    pgList_insert(pgList, pg);
  }
}
```

```
int pg_read(FILE *fp, pg_t *pgp){

  if(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s ", pgp->cod, pgp->nome, pgp->classe)){
    stat_read(fp, &pgp->b_stat);
    pgp->equip = equipArray_init();
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass a pointer of the file pointer to the second function and use it in the fscanf but it didn't worked either

Comment: What does `fscanf()` return if it fails to read anything?

Comment: How do you know whether `fscanf` returns `EOF` or `3` (or any other non-0 value)? Both will be treated as `true` in your condition.

Comment: What is the content of your input file? What is the output of your program? How do you print? Please edit your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with sample input and output as well as expected output.

Comment: and pleas show `stat_read()` which obviously uses the same `FILE *`

Comment: @Gabbo, <calls the second one "from the start"> likely because `stat_read(fp, &pgp->b_stat)` reset the file.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

You can try to get your while-loop into your other function or
Try returning FILE* in the second function or
use fscanf in a while loop such as:

```
    while( fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s",v1,v2,v3) != EOF){
    // code here     
}
```

EDIT: by the things i meant you could do sth. like this

```
void pgList_read(FILE *fp, pgList_t pgList){
    pg_t pg;
    while( !feof(pg_read(fp, &pg)) ){
      pg_print(stdout, &pg, NULL);
      pgList_insert(pgList, pg);
    }
  }
```

and the second function'd be sth like

```
FILE* pg_read(FILE *fp, pg_t *pgp){
    
      if(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s ", pgp->cod, pgp->nome, pgp->classe) !=EOF){
// need to check you'r reading the last item trio correctly just in case
        stat_read(fp, &pgp->b_stat);
        pgp->equip = equipArray_init();
        return fp;
      }
      return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: With this, you don't know how many successful extractions there was.  It could have only extracted `v1`, or `v1` and `v2` for example. Instead of `!= EOF` I suggest `== 3`.

Comment: you can't pass a `FILE *` by value in the way you mean it. Every stdio function that is called with that pointer will necessarly affect the result of any subsequent operation with the same pointer